# how can i allow aws IAM permission only specific time

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am trying to make IAM polish to only work from 9AM to 10AM.

Since I am not corder, so I am struggle with this...

help me plz....

I tried to add conditions:

```
"Condition": {
    "DateGreaterThan": {"aws:CurrentTime": "2021-04-20T09:00:00Z"},
    "DateLessThan": {"aws:CurrentTime": "2021-04-20T10:00:00Z"}
```

but.. in this way, i have to update manually every day..
So i tried ...

```
"Condition": {
    "DateGreaterThan": {"aws:CurrentTime": "****-**-**T09:00:00Z"},
    "DateLessThan": {"aws:CurrentTime": "****-**-**T10:00:00Z"}
```

but this is not working.

How can i accomplish working depends on time not depends on date..?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use wildcards in datetime operations in IAM. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_condition_operators.html#Conditions_Date)

> Wildcards are **not permitted** for date condition operators.

So you either have to use full date/time or timestamp. To automate this, you can create a **lambda function** that is [triggered on a schedule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html). The lambda would use AWS sdk to update your policy everyday.

Comment: Thank you for your advice.
I will dig the Lambda and AWS SDK...